# Powershell & operator stops working

Tags: powershell, logparser

I have a script in PowerShell that calls LogParser.  Early in the script I define the path to the executable and tests its path:

```
#Define path to log parser executable
$logParser = '\\hostname\logparser22\LogParser.exe'
if (! $(Test-Path $logParser) )
    {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Could not access: $logParser"
    return
    }
```

Then later down the script I call LogParser:

```
$sessionData =  & $logParser "SELECT * FROM $logPath where data LIKE `'Contoso\\$user`'" -i:csv -nSkipLines:4 -headers:on -stats:off -o:csv
```

This works file for awhile during the PowerShell session, but if run enough times it stops working eventually.  Doing a little debugging once I've entered a broken shell, the below does not even produce the normal help that comes back when calling LogParser without parameters:

```
& $LogParser
```

However if I open a new PowerShell session running the SAME exact command, it works and calls LogParser and I get the standard response from it when not passing any parameters.

What I've come down to is & is broken somehow.  Has anyone seen this and know of a fix\workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try using an other way to start you external process with a Cmdlet :

```
$logParser = '\\hostname\logparser22\LogParser.exe'
$allArgs = ("SELECT * FROM $logPath where data LIKE `'Contoso\\$user`'", "-i:csv", "-nSkipLines:4", "-headers:on", "-stats:off -o:csv")
$ps = Start-Process -FilePath $logParser -ArgumentList $allargs -Wait -Passthru -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput $tempoutputfile -RedirectStandardError $temperrorfile;
$ps.WaitForExit() # block till exe finish
$ps.ExitCode;
```

You should have more explanations on the error.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it saved my butt. I couldn't understand why when calling an executable from my PowerShell script kept failing after a certain period of time. Now when I use `Start-Process`, all works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. As mentioned in the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/665809), the workaround in Powershell V2 is to put `[GC]::Collect()` in your loop that writes to the console.

The `&<command>` is the preferred way of calling out to an external `.exe`. There is an excellent post about [how to set up your external calls with arguments](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/).

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to [this defect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/665809/dos-commands-stop-working-after-executing-bit-of-code-in-a-script) in how PowerShell handles large volumes of console output, which could easily happen with the LogParser.  This is supposedly fixed in PowerShell 3.0.